# Global variables, Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

Can I do this ?

```
var global = 0;

var truc = $.getJSON("events.json", function(json){
 //alert("JSON Data: " + json[0].titre);
  global = json;
});
```

I want to keep the contents of json and work with it outside the function.
If it was C, I would just keep the pointer but I don't know what to do with JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can do that

Comment: I wish it would work. Guess what, If I put alert(json) at the end of my code, it displays zero !

Comment: immediately after? of course it failed. the request hasn't finished yet. the variable `global` won't have a new value until the request completes

Comment: That's true, this is a callback function after all. Alright just give me a minute then.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the details on how json works, so I cannot say what happens in your case, but this simple test works as a simplified example on how your global variable will actually work:

```
var global = 0;

function callTest(arr) {
    //alert("JSON Data: " + json[0].titre);
    global = arr;
}

var array = new Array("w", "q");
callTest(array);
alert(global);
```

This means that it has something to do with how json works. One thing: Are you sure the function initialized with json is actually run before you test with `alert(global)` ?

Comment: It wasn't. There's a 30 ms lag waiting for my server to send the JSON.
What I did is that all the code that needs this JSON will start from the callback.